# How to split multiple values of keys into separate keys in an Array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this Array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( [value] => Cooking, [occurence] => 1 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [value] => Music, [occurence] => 1 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [value] => Football,Cooking, [occurence] => 1 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [value] => Travel, [occurence] => 1 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [value] => Cooking,Reading, [occurence] => 2 ) 
        [5] => Array ( [value] => Football,Travel, [occurence] => 1 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [value] => Football, [occurence] => 1 ) 
        [7] => Array ( [value] => Music,Cooking, [occurence] => 1 ) 
        [8] => Array ( [value] => Reading,Travel, [occurence] => 1 )
    )
)
```

The [2], [4], [5], [7] and [8] have 2 values for the key [value].
What I want to do is to split the 2 values of these keys in different keys.

The new values should not go to new Arrays, but they will be added to the similar existing Arrays.

For example, if I break the [2] (Football,Cooking) the result will be that the occurence of [6] (Football) will be incremented by 1 and the [occurence] of [0] (Cooking) will be incremented by 1 also.

Thank you !
Yann

Answer (score 1):

```
$newdata = array()
foreach($array as $data) { // $array being the inner array with the 9 elements
   $keys = explode(',', $data['value']);
   foreach ($keys as $subkey) {
       $newdata[$subkey]++;
   }
}
```

which would give you something like

```
$newdata = array(
    'Cooking' => 4,
    'Football' => 3
    etc...
);
```

Not sure how you want your structure to look afterwards, but at least this'll do the inventory for you.

Comment: Thanx, but that's not exactly what I was looking for. I think my problem starts from a badly designed mysql table. It keeps 2 values inside a cell separated by comma and when I query the table I don't know how to put each value to a different key in the array, so they end up in the same key. Thanx anyway.

Comment: Split the values when you fetch the row, then assign them to the array manually, rather than as part of the fetch command.